# two integer devisor sum

Tags: java, arrays, integer-division

I wrote this code but in result i got wrong answer and i don't know why .
I have to get 3 integer a, b ,x . then find a,b divisor and if the divisor's sum was not more than x then res++ and finally print res.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testQuestion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int[] resB = new int[b];
        int[] resA = new int[a];
        int res = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            if (a % i == 0)
                resA[i - 1] += i;
            if (b % i == 0)
                resB[i - 1] += i;
        }
        for (int i : resA) {
            if (i > 0)
                for (int j : resB) {
                    if (i + j <= x && j > 0) {
                        res++;
                    }
                }
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share more details on WHAT is not working along with reproduceable examples?

Comment: This is the question

Comment: Poopak wakes up .he remembers that he had a dream but he does not remember the details of this dream ...

Poopak knows that he had two bags of marbles in his dream, with at least one marble in each bag. Poopak knows that the number of marbles in the first bag is divisible by the numberaa And the number of marbles in the second bag is divisible by the number bbhave been. Poopak also remembers that his two bags were not too heavy and at most maximumxx The marble was in two bags.

Comment: At the same time, Poopak sees Tuk and tells him the story. Took also very quickly counts the number of different dreams that Poopak may have had and tells him this number

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this helps, seems that you have 2 storage, A and B. By looping A, you might miss out B. **Example** B has 10 records, A has only 1 record, and A is equal or less than 0 then you will not loop. To ensure that, loop both A and B and check if it's >0.

-But then again if A is empty, you will not loop B.

```
    for (int i : resA) {
        for (int j : resB) {
           if(j > 0 && i > 0) {
             if (i + j <= x) {
                    res++;
             }
           }
        }
    }
```

**Updated**:

Firstly: make one variable by removing resB. Leave  int[] resA = new int[a];

Secondly:  loop A and add into resA

Thirdly:  loop B And check division. Then compare if sum of any B with any A has > x.

Fourth: You might then make adjustment if you want to check an empty A should make B add with 0. Or well, you might not count it at all. Depends on what you need. Same thing might be done to B if empty.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: suggestion. would this comply to your needs?

Comment: also check if you need anything divisible by 1? as anything divide by 1 is always modulus 0.